# Remove object if key in object is zero

Tags: jquery

I am trying to build a payload that takes in 2 values, Name and Quantity. Each quantity is associated with the name. What I am trying to do is if the quantity equals zero, then that object with the name and quantity is not added to my payload.

```js
  var myQuantity = $('input[name="quantity[]"]').map(function() {return $(this).val();}).get();
var myName = $('[name="name[]"]').map(function(){return $(this).text();}).get();

  
var len = myQuantity.length;
var data = []
  
for (var x = 0; x < len; x++){
  var element = {
    "name"     : myName[x],
    "quantity" : myQuantity[x] 
  }
  data.push(element);
}
console.log(data);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span name="name[]" class="name">1</span><input type="text" name="quantity[]" class="quantity" value="1"><br>
<span name="name[]" class="name">2</span><input type="text" name="quantity[]" class="quantity" value="0"><br>
<span name="name[]" class="name">3</span><input type="text" name="quantity[]" class="quantity" value="5"><br>
```

Comment: try wrapping the data.push in an if > 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add that only if it is not empty.

```
for (var x = 0; x < len; x++){
    var element = {
        "name"     : myName[x],
        "quantity" : myQuantity[x]  
    }
    if(myQuantity[x] != 0){
        data.push(element);
    }
  }
  console.log(data);
```